# Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute - Unity 3d

Tags: c#, foreach, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with a code of the game I'm doing.
I 'm trying to do that when the player a certain amount of meters away on the z object is removed , but the test I ran into my unity froze and I went out this error: Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute.

Here is the code

```
    void Update()
{
    foreach (GameObject gm in GenerateManager.Instante.BloquesGenerados)
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(PlayerManager.Instanse.gameObject.transform.position, gm.transform.position) > 25)
        {
            Destroy(gm);
            GenerateManager.Instante.BloquesGenerados.Remove(gm);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't modify collection in `foreach`. Instead of that use `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `ToList()`, it will create a new collection with same items:

```
foreach (GameObject gm in GenerateManager.Instante.BloquesGenerados.ToList())
```

You cannot modify (`GenerateManager.Instante.BloquesGenerados.Remove`) collection you're iterating over with `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate backwards:

```
for(int i=GenerateManager.Instante.BloquesGenerados.Count - 1; i>=0; i--){
    var gm = GenerateManager.Instante.BloquesGenerados[i];
    if(Vector3.Distance(PlayerManager.Instanse.gameObject.transform.position,gm.transform.position) > 25){ 

        Destroy(gm); 
        GenerateManager.Instante.BloquesGenerados.Remove(gm);
    }
```

You won't have to copy the collection. You save time and space (memory wise).

Comment: It's easy to get a bug in this case if you'll start to complicate your logic inside the loop. You win by performance but lose readability and maintainability.

Comment: @aush I am afraid there's no complication. Iterating backwards will simply allow you to pop out elements without having to jump over indexes.

Comment: @Gabe you can just start removing more than one item at time and the whole idea fails.

Comment: @aush Put it down on a piece of paper and see for yourself :)

Comment: @aush If you check again, you'll see that you're trying to remove an item by an unexisting index. ( i - 1 where i = 0)

Comment: @Gabe yes, that's what I'm talking about when I talk about complication of your business logic. In real projects it happens every time. This is kind of preventive optimization that can lead to hours of debugging.

Comment: @aush Don't eat soup with a spoon you may swallow it

Comment: @Gabe You are writing code that either misleading (you should put comment that explains what you can and what you cannot do inside your loop to avoid bugs, and yes, no one reads comments) or just not complete (you should put an index guard inside your loop).

Comment: I agree with @aush completely. You shouldn't only think about your code working or not working now; you should think about how it can be modified, by you or another maintainer, and what bugs can be created by it. What if you call another method inside this loop? And then someone uses this collection inside this method? There's a thousand ways for this code to create hard bugs in the future. Performance gain doesn't justify this.

Comment: @golergka You are hyperbolizing a trivial situation. It has not been given a stable context (multithreading etc.) . Bugs can derive from anything depending on what your target is; the programmer has the responsability to provide reliable safe checks etc. to avoid other bottlenecks in the future. Copying the collection can provide an outdated dataset and in a inefficient way as well. Believe me, I write real-world applications every day - you're not complaining on the right thing.

Comment: It is the programmer responsibility not only to provide safe checks, but also to remove the necessity of these safe checks and make code more resilient. In this solution, you're adding a potential failure. You're making doing correct things harder and making mistakes easier, while you have to do the opposite. [This article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/) explains in great detail what I'm taking about.

Comment: Also, I think that the majority of us here "write read-world applications every day", so it doesn't really sound as a compelling reason to believe your judgement.

Comment: Does providing an indexed access to a collection a potential danger? The author has not mentioned in what kind of threaded environment he is working in and what parallel operations may ocurr. (given a multithreaded system, the object could have been removed already in the collection but not in the clone - then you are trying to remove an inexisting element). There is no implicit failsafe check there.

Comment: Multithreaded environments are highly unusual for Unity3d code, so I go from the assumption that he works in single thread.